How can I get windows localhost to expose subdomains to nextJS?
My windows host file includes:

127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 subsite.localhost

When I run my NextJS project on port 3001, I can access the site using:

http://localhost:3001
http://subsite.localhost:3001

However, NextJS always sees the hostname as localhost only.
I've tried using middleware.js but:

NextRequest.nextUrl.host === localhost:3001
NextRequest.headers.get("host") === 127.0.0.1:38607

I'm running Windows11 with Docker and WSL2, my terminal is in Ubuntu. Does anyone know what is wrong with this junk?

I usually use req.headers.get('host') and it has been working for me earlier.

I'm getting a similar issue with AWS loadbalancer, any help would be appreciated,

Could be you need to use X-Forwarded-For. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/x-forwarded-headers.html
